# Dapper wrong value for data base Column Value

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper with C# to get result from a store procedure.
The Table (`TPTable`) has `Pid` as Primary key, and `Value` as name for second column, and some other columns.
I have a store that is: `select * from TPTable`.

When i call `QueryAsync<TPTableModel>` method the result comes the value of Value Column is allways the same as Primary Key

Let say in DB

Pid = 1, Value = 2

Pid = 2, Value = 568

The Result will be a list of {{Pid=1,Value=1},{Pid=2,Value=2}}.

Why i will getting `Value` equals to PrimaryKey, everytime?

Comment: That's very odd and concerning. I want to investigate, but this sounds like something that should be done on github, ideally with a minimal repro that I can use to actually see it happening. First question: what is the server? SQL Server? Oracle? (This mainly impacts how I can reproduce it, etc)

Comment: Its SQL Server. I have noted that if i replace "select * " for "select Pid, Value", it works. I will try replicate in a small project in GitHub.

Comment: I'd be very very interesting in what the columns are in your table, and what the class looks like. It *could* be something to do with badly named backing fields and case precedence. Or if this is "azure", there was a bug (now fixed) relating to an extra (unrequested) column appearing relating to PK/ID data.

Comment: I think the most likely cause here is the "and some other columns". What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Is not with Dapper. I was repro a small project and i found the store has a inner join with an sql user defined type. This type has a Column named Value that has the values of primary key. When i call Dapper with select * on store it will fill the value of user defined type.

[image: PrintScreen in sqlserver]

Comment: Yup, that would definitely do it. As far as dapper is concerned "column called value, I mapped it to a property called value; what did I do wrong?" :)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine locally:

```
[Fact]
public async void SO35470588_WrongValuePidValue()
{
    // nuke, rebuild, and populate the table
    try { connection.Execute("drop table TPTable"); } catch { }
    connection.Execute(@"
create table TPTable (Pid int not null primary key identity(1,1), Value int not null);
insert TPTable (Value) values (2), (568)");

    // fetch the data using the query in the question, then force to a dictionary
    var rows = (await connection.QueryAsync<TPTable>("select * from TPTable"))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Pid);

    // check the number of rows
    rows.Count.IsEqualTo(2);

    // check row 1
    var row = rows[1];
    row.Pid.IsEqualTo(1);
    row.Value.IsEqualTo(2);

    // check row 2
    row = rows[2];
    row.Pid.IsEqualTo(2);
    row.Value.IsEqualTo(568);
}
public class TPTable
{
    public int Pid { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'd be happy to investigate, but a repro would be much appreciated.